# Redux sagas Fetch only once when same id is dispatched multiple times

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I’m getting a user from my API and store it in my state so I don’t have to fetch it again.
Problem is that multiple components requests the user at the same time resulting in multiple concurrent fetch requests.

Is there a good pattern to avoid this?

This is my saga

```
function* watchUserRequests() {
    yield takeEvery(actionTypes.USER_REQUESTED, userRequested);
}

function* userRequested(action) {
    const {id} = action.payload;
    let user = yield select(state => state.users.all[id]);
    // cancel if user exists      
    if (user) return;
    user = yield call(userApi.get, id);
    yield put(userActions.userLoaded(id, banner));
}
```

Actions

```
export function userRequested(id) {
    return {type: types.USER_REQUESTED, payload: {id}};
}

export function userLoaded(id, user) {
    return {type: types.USER_LOADED, payload: {id, user}};
}
```

Comment: To avoid the concurrent fetch requests you can store in state not only fetched users but also those being fetched. I can see how that is not pretty but can't think of a way to avoid that. You could write some higher order function to at least isolate some of the logic.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea. I tried to dispatch a USER_LOADING action at the start of userRequested function to store this information. But all the USER_REQUESTED action were faster and already on the way before the first USER_LOADING action reached the reducer.

Comment: You will have to change the state in the reducer on userRequested action.

Comment: Did you consider using `takeLatest` instead of `takeEvery`?

Comment: I still need every request when different ids are requested. What i did finally was to preload every user I needed before the components started to request them.

Comment: In another saga I solved the same problem by accumulating all ids during 50 milliseconds and then dispatch a new action to request multiple items in one fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem in another saga. The "type" here can be ignored

- Accumulate the requested id in an ids object:
- Dispatch action to fetch all accumulated ids
- Debounce fetch for 50 milliseconds
- While waiting... Add new Ids to the ids object
- While waiting... Cancel fetch task to give you 50 new milliseconds
- Commit fetch
- Clear tasks and ids

Code:

```
let ids = {};
let tasks = {};

function* watchCounterRequests() {
  yield takeEvery(actionTypes.COUNTER_REQUESTED, accumulate);
}

function* watchCounterFetchRequests() {
  yield takeEvery(actionTypes.COUNTER_FETCH_REQUESTED, counterFetchRequested);
}

function* accumulate(action) {
  const {id, type} = action.payload;
  if (!ids[type]) ids[type] = {};

  ids[type][id] = true;
  if (tasks[type]) {
    yield cancel(tasks[type]);
  }
  tasks[type] = yield fork(fetchCounters, type);
}

function* fetchCounters(type) {
  yield call(delay, 50);

  yield put({
    type: actionTypes.COUNTER_FETCH_REQUESTED,
    payload: {type: type, ids: Object.keys(ids[type])},
  });

  delete ids[type];
  delete tasks[type];
}

function* counterFetchRequested(action) {
  const {ids, type} = action.payload;
  let typeName = type + 'Ids';
  let req = {
    [typeName]: ids
  };
  yield put(counterActions.loadCounters(req));
}

export default [watchCounterRequests, watchCounterFetchRequests];
```

Most of this comes from here: https://marmelab.com/blog/2016/10/18/using-redux-saga-to-deduplicate-and-group-actions.html

Answer (score 3):

It think you are looking for something like

```
import {
 take,
 fork,
 cancel,
} from 'redux-saga';

const takeLatestDeep = (pattern, identifier, fn, ...args) => fork(function* () {
  const tasks = {};

  while(true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern);
    const id = identifier(action);

    if (tasks[id]) {
      yield cancel(tasks[id]);
    } 

    tasks[id] = yield fork(fn, ...args.concat(action));
  }
})
```

That you can use like this

```
yield takeLatestDeep(
   actionTypes.USER_REQUESTED,
   action => action.payload.id,
   fetchLegacyRecipientsSaga,
   ...args 
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks really clean. But I think I need to read up on generators some to understand this fully.

Comment: I've copied your code into my app and have it magically working. Would you mind explaining how and why this effectively deduplicates requests?

Comment: @amageddian : this will group your calls to `fn` by the result of `identifier`.
So if two actions are taken by `takeLatestDeep` and `identifier` output the same result for both of them, `takeLatestDeep` will cancel the task for the first one because `tasks[id]` exists.