# Cancel previous redux-saga task if a specific parameter is same

Tags: redux-saga

`GET_CHART_DATA` is an action which calls and api to fetche the chart data based on chartId. Suppose `GET_CHART_DATA` is called with `chartId='123'` and api sends a request to server with that chartId. The request is in pending state. I dispatch same action `GET_CHART_DATA` with same chartId again i.e.123, in which case previous request of that same chartId should get cancelled. (Note: with chartId other parameters are going but those parameters are different, that is why I want to cancel old request which will have old parameters)

The catch is that there might be other requests to `GET_CHART_DATA` with different chartIds. Now I don't want to cancel those requests. I just want to cancel the previous request with same chart Id.

This is my action.js and sagas.js file. (sample)

```
   // action.js
    export function getChartData(params) {
      return {
        type: 'GET_CHART_DATA',
        params, // { chartid: '123' }
      };
    }

export function cancelPreviousDataCall(chartId) {
  return {
    type: 'CANCEL_PREVIOUS_DATA_CALL',
    chartId,
  };
}

// sagas.js
export function* getChartData(params) {
  try {
    const { result } = yield race({
      result: call(Api.getChartData, params.chartid),
      cancel: take('CANCEL_PREVIOUS_DATA_CALL'),
    });
  } catch (error) {}
}

   function* watchGetChartData() {
      while (true) {
        const { params } = yield take('GET_CHART_DATA');
        yield fork(getChartData, params);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572331/redux-sagas-fetch-only-once-when-same-id-is-dispatched-multiple-times#answer-53465495

Comment: you can use `takeLatest` in case of `race` conditions. https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html

Comment: Check this answer (a similar use case): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53743660/633969

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the forked tasks for each particular `chartId`. You can then cancel the task if its still running. For example, your `watchGetCharData` could be something like this:

```
function* watchGetChartData() {
    let tasksByChartId = {}
    while (true) {
        const { params } = yield take('GET_CHART_DATA')
        if (tasksByChartId[params.chartId] && tasksByChartId[params.chartId].isRunning()) {
            tasksByChartId[params.chartId].cancel()
        }
        tasksByChartId[params.chartId] = yield fork(getChartData, params)
    }
}
```

With this you should no longer need the `CANCEL_PREVIOUS_DATA_CALL` action